# How can i be sure i'm using EC2-VPC and not EC2-Classic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm using an old account but i'm a beginner at AWS so i need some help to make sure im using VPC and not Classic so i don't lose my instances when they retire classic. I've read other topics that say that if an instance has VPC-ID defined it means that it's on a VPC, but i just want to make sure.
I have 5 instances, 4 of them have VPC-ID: VPC name, but there's an old instance that's like this:VPC-ID: -
Does this VPC-ID thing work for RDS too? Meaning if it's defined, it's in a VPC?

Thank you for your help and patience

Comment: IIRC in RDS it shows a subnetID to indicate it's in a VPC. Your one instance does appear to be classic.

Comment: so if the subnetID is defined it means it's in a VPC right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct